# How do I get Google Maps to display a location based on Lat/Long

Tags: google-maps

Currently, we can accept the Lat/Long coordinate correctly, and save it correctly, but when we go back to the map later - the pin snaps to the nearest road and not to the exact lat/long we entered.

Has anybody encountered this, and if so, how did you get around this?

```
place = response.Placemark[0];
point = new GLatLng(place.Point.coordinates[1],place.Point.coordinates[0]);
marker = new GMarker(point);
me.map.addOverlay(marker);  
me.map.setCenter(point, zoom);
```

When we show this, the coordinates snap to the road, not the actual coordinates.

Comment: Showing some code would help. I'm guessing somewhere in the initialization a marker is being placed when it shouldn't be

Comment: Not enough code. What is `response` the response to? And how are you "going back to the map later"? The code executed then must be different, or it would behave the same.

Answer (score 1):

Don't run a coordinate though the geocoding api. If you pass a coordinate to the API it will reverse geocode it. Which is finding the nearest feature.

As you have a coordinate, just build a GLatLng directly with it. parseFloat is recommended.